# An extension of Gaussian Isoperimetry

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, probability-distributions, oc.optimization-and-control, mg.metric-geometry

The Gaussian isoperimetric inequality (Tsirelson,Sudakov, Borell) states that among all sets of given Gaussian measure in the n-dimensional Euclidean space, half-spaces have the minimal Gaussian boundary measure.
Suppose we put an additional restriction on the set, that it should be symmetric about the origin. Then can we conclude that quarter-spaces (intuitively the first and third quadrant in 2-dimensions, say) have the minimal Gaussian boundary measure?

Comment: Also, if possible, could someone please suggest a more readable version of the Gaussian isoperimetry proofs, and possibly other related references on Gaussian measures (like lecture notes or surveys available free on the internet)?

Comment: A bit off topic, but you could find this helpful: a nice review connecting concentration (and isoperimetric inequalities) to Markov chains. This allows to study discrete analogues of the picture.

Yann Ollivier, A survey of Ricci curvature for metric spaces and Markov chains (pdf) http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/surveycurvmarkov.pdf 

Comment: A little bit of computation shows that 'quarter-spaces' (or a symmetrization of halfspaces around the origin) is clearly not the best we can do. For example in two dimensions, just a circle of measure 1/2 has smaller boundary measure than the above set. But the question remains open.
Also, thanks everyone, for the references.

Comment: Following up on Ryan's suggestions, here's a paper by Barthe (subscription probably required) whose introduction suggests that the problem as you stated, and the analogous problem on the sphere, are open and difficult: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=81315

Comment: Nice find, Mark.

Comment: Oh! Need to recheck my calculations, then. Thanks! BTW I was trying to explore these results in the context of studying noise stability of Boolean functions.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the optimizer is actually a "strip"; i.e., a set of the form {$x : -t \leq x_1 \leq t$}.  But I'm somewhat sure that the solution to this problem is not known.  You might take a look at the discussion surrounding after Corollary 3.6 in this paper by Klartag and Regev:

http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/140/

Barthe may also have some relevant papers.

Comment: Suppose we are looking at sets of measure 1/2 say. Then t as above is root(2) erfinverse(.5) which is roughly .67449
The boundary measure in this case is .635553
Compared to a boundary measure of .588 in the case of a circle of measure 1/2.
Assuming my calculations are correct.

Comment: Yeah, that's very possible.  So maybe a sphere is best in general?  
Another good question (which might suggest the answer) is whether the analogous isoperimetric problem on the surface of the sphere is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Answering more @Bratt's comment than the original question: Talagrand's book

people.math.jussieu.fr/~talagran/book.ps.gz

Seems quite nice.